# How to read a .dif file and paste into dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I’m having a little issue trying to open a .dif file using Python and convert it into a dataframe… Do you know how to open these kind of files?

Comment: I am in the same boat here. I can read it in plain text, but that's of no value. I need to read it in as a dataframe.

Answer (score -1):

You can read dif file like this:

```
Path = r"C:\Users\user\Documents\datasets\sample.dif"
content = open(Path, 'rb').read()
print(content)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this simply reads thing in as plain text (and not formatted as a dataframe, with rows/cols). Have you found alternative methods to read these files in, or possibly have a library to reference?